# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'std_msgs' - Gazebo installation

Tags: ros, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym, rospy

I am trying to install gym_gazebo on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system according to https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo

Everything is getting installed correctly, however, while trying to run **python circuit2_turtlebot_lidar_qlearn.py** , I get error as

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'std_msgs'.`

This should be part of **ros_comm** project which I have installed but still I cannot see **std_msgs** related code file anywhere.

Can someone please point me to how can I install std_msgs, so that I can get rid of this error message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you source the `setup.bash` of ROS or your workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be very straightforward:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-<ros version>-std-msgs
```

Just replace  with kinetic, or whatever you are using.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update. After doing some more research, I could install this from github and made some changes in folder structure so that code could recognize the location. However, now I am getting following error for this line "from std_msgs.msg import Header".
    **ImportError: cannot import name 'Header'**

I checked my folder "std_msgs/msg" and found several files with .msg extension and among them there is a Header.msg file. However, since it is not .py file, import command does not recognize it. Is there any other step to convert these files to .PY file?

Comment: The thing is that ROS usually generates .h and .py files for you. Therefore I would say that maybe your Python instance doesn't know about ROS. I usually add ROS to my PYTHONPATH, here is my .bashrc c/p: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Comment: Finally, I could install std_msgs with the help of tutorial from ROS wiki and not getting error anymore. Earlier I was following the steps given in the github link for gym-gazebo. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Accepting the answer as it solves the original error.